# How to have a default number set to my picker view

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a two picker views I am working with that has a value of 1 - 1000. I want one UIPickerView to have a default value of 1000 so when the user loads the app the first picker is already defaulted to 1 but the second will be defaulted to 1000. How can I accomplish this? Code below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var startNumberLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var firstNumberPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNumberLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNumberPicker: UIPickerView!



let firstNumber = Array(1...1000)
let lastNumber = Array(1...1000)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstNumberPicker.dataSource = self
    firstNumberPicker.delegate = self
    firstNumberPicker.tag = 1

    lastNumberPicker.dataSource = self
    lastNumberPicker.delegate = self
    lastNumberPicker.tag = 2

}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    var returnRow: String!

    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        returnRow = "\(firstNumber[row])"
    } else {
        returnRow = "\(lastNumber[row])"
    }
    return returnRow
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    var returnIndex: Int = 0

    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        returnIndex = firstNumber.count
    } else {
        returnIndex = lastNumber.count
    }
    return returnIndex
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        startNumberLabel.text = "\(firstNumber[row])"
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        lastNumberLabel.text = "\(lastNumber[row])"
    }
}
```

With help from Shivam I was put on the right path this is the final code added to the func viewDidLoad()

```
lastNumberPicker.selectRow(999, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the defults of picker in viewDidload as per follow....

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
    Picker.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
}
```

here you can change values of row and 0 according to your requirements, may this will help you... :)

Comment: I will give this a try. If I have a question I will respond here shortly. Thank you :)

Comment: sure , and up vote the answer now and if it will work then don't forget to tick it right ...:)

Comment: Thanks Shivam your answer got me on the right track.